# User.get () is broken in Grails 2.0, returns me null

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have been struggling for days to return the user but I do not want, I pass the id of this logged in, but it returns null. Someone else has this happened?

```
    println "User ID: ${springSecurityService.principal.id}" //If you print the Id

    def id = springSecurityService.principal.id
    def user = User.get(id)

    println "User: ${user}" // Not found, it prints null
```

I need help...

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService), you should be able to just do:

```
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I try that, and does not work either =/, any other suggestions?. Or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: //def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        def user = Usuario.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
        
        println "User: ${user}" // Not found, it prints null
      
        Evento event = Evento.get(params.id)

         if(!evento.findByAllAsistentes(usuario)){
                    println "Asistent to Event"
                }

Comment: Null shows me what I want is to bring me to the User that is in session, to look after if you are in the list of attendees ... but as I returned null, I can not find the user in the audience ...

Comment: pasting multi-line code into comments isn't going to help understanding though :-(